# RadioButton bound to the Enum shows error on the unselected radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two radio buttons with Right and Left options:

```
<RadioButton Content="Right" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Direction, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Right}"/>
<RadioButton Content="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Direction, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Left}"/>
```

The following Enum to Boolean converter code

```
public class EnumBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string parameterString = parameter as string;
    if (parameterString == null)
      return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
      return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    object parameterValue = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), parameterString);

    return parameterValue.Equals(value);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string parameterString = parameter as string;
    if (parameterString == null)
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    return Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString);
  }
}
```

Now when I select the radio button Right, the Left option shows error( a red border arround the radiobutton control with Left); and vise versa
how to fix this?

**Found the solution, adding it just in case anyone needs.**

Problem is, it is trying to pick the validation style from the application. 
So I have to decorate the each element of the Radio button it with

```
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: It shows a red border arround the radiobutton, I think it is the binding problem

Comment: in output window do you see any message?

Comment: No Error/Message in the output

Comment: `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"` did the trick